# Is _node variable in LIST_FOREACH() macro added only for code readability?

Tags: c, macros, readability, function-definition

In a macro I noticed that there is a variable `_node` which seems superfluous as it could be removed and fully replaced with V.

The only time it is used on its own is in the test expression in the for loop.

`_node` even has an underscore prefix, which implies it is an internal use only variable.

Is `_node` present in this macro to make it easier for folks to read?

Macro

```
#define LIST_FOREACH(L, S, M, V)\
ListNode *_node = NULL;\
ListNode *V = NULL;\
for(V = _node = L->S; _node != NULL; V = _node = _node->M)
```

---

Example usage

```
void List_destroy(List * list)
{
    LIST_FOREACH(list, first, next, cur) { 
        if (cur->prev){
            free(cur->prev);
        }
    }
    free(list->last);
    free(list);
}
```

Created Typedefs

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value; 
} ListNode;

typedef struct List { 
    int count; 
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;
```

Comment: The macro makes the code unreadable.:)

Comment: I believe `_node` is a reserved identifier in this scope, too.

Comment: The fixed name `_node` makes it impossible to use this macro twice in the same block because `_node` would get redefined. Removing the `_node` variable allows the macro to be used twice in the same block, but not with the same `V` parameter because the corresponding variable would get redefined. Changing the macro to define the variables in the scope of the `for` loop fixes those problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The macro makes the code unreadable. That is it is a very bad style of programming.

If to substitute the macro in this function

```
void List_destroy(List * list)
{
    LIST_FOREACH(list, first, next, cur) { 
        if (cur->prev){
            free(cur->prev);
        }
    }
    free(list->last);
    free(list);
}
```

for its extension then you will get

```
void List_destroy(List * list)
{
    ListNode *_node = NULL;
    ListNode *cur = NULL
    
    for( cur = _node = list->first; _node != NULL; cur = _node = _node->next )
    {
        if (cur->prev){
            free(cur->prev);
        }
    }
    free(list->last);
    free(list);
}
```

it is seen at once that the variables `cur` and `_node` should be declared in the for loop that is where they are used. Moreover the variable `_node` is just redundant.

The function can be rewritten the following way

```
void List_destroy(List * list)
{
    for( ListNode *cur = list->first; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next )
    {
        free( cur->prev );
    }
    
    free( list->last );
    free( list );
}
```

But it is even more simpler and correct to define the function like

```
void List_destroy( List *list )
{
    while ( list->first != NULL )
    {
        ListNode *tmp = list->first;
        list->first = lits->first->next;
        free(  tmp );
    }

    list->last = NULL;    
    list->count = 0;
}
```

The function shall not free the pointed list itself. For example the user can define the list like

```
List list = { .count = 0, .first = NULL, .last = NULL };
```

that is it is not necessary that an object of the type `struct List` is allocated dynamically.

Also it is totally unclear whether the data member `value` points to a dynamically allocated object and why it is not freed.

So in general the function should look like

```
void List_destroy( List *list )
{
    while ( list->first != NULL )
    {
        ListNode *tmp = list->first;
        list->first = lits->first->next;
        free( tmp->value );
        free(  tmp );
    }

    list->last = NULL;    
    list->count = 0;
}
```

So in my opinion you found somewhere a very bad code that does not deserve to be discussed about.:)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the point of the `_node` variable is to make it so the body of the loop can freely modify `V` without affecting the iteration.  I wouldn't have written it this way; I would have instead used

```
#define LIST_FOREACH(L, S, M, V) \
    for(ListNode *V = (L)->S; V; V = V->M)
```

because I think not polluting the outer scope with variable declarations, and allowing `LIST_FOREACH` to be nested, are more important.  But I can see the argument for the separate `V` and `_node`.